# php: property of custom type

Tags: php, properties

I am trying to write the following code, though it is wrong it will probably demonstrate best why I am trying to do.

```
class myClass
{
    private $name = "";
    private $startAddress = new myAddress();  // this is the issue
    private $endAddress = new myAddress();    // this is the issue
}
```

How can I accomplish this properly?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <?php
class myClass {
   private $endAddress;
   public function __construct() {
       $this->endAddress = new myAddress();
   }
 }
```

Take advantage of the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), which is called every time you create a new object.

Comment: @alex: If you omit the visibility, `public` is assumed.

Comment: @KingCrunch I like to show it. Otherwise it feels like I'm still using PHP4 :P

Comment: Thank you all very much! So speedy with the response! This was a big help. Thanks again! :)